# Why Access don't update this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a table called `Contacts` with one field called `Contacts.Title`.

In MS-Access, If I do a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE (((Contacts.Title) Like "%Boss%");
```

It works and found 70 rows. But if I try to do the next update, it doesn't find any row:

```
UPDATE Contacts
SET Contacts.Title = "Boss"
WHERE (((Contacts.Title) Like "%Boss%");
```

If I do the same query in the SQL Server (the table in Access is vinculated from a SQL Server) it works, changing the 70 rows. This question is not how to do that (because I just did in SQL Server without problems), is about why MS Access didn't find any row in the update?

I did something wrong? Or I'm  ignoring something?

Comment: Your brackets don't match. Is that just a typo?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the MS Access wildcard is `*` not `%`

```
UPDATE Contacts
SET Contacts.Title = "Boss"
WHERE (((Contacts.Title) Like "*Boss*");
```

Comment: But in the Select, the rows appear, but not in the Update. Why?

Comment: It's certainly unexpected behaviour. So this is a table in MS Access right? what do you mean by 'vinculated'?